# Deploy multiple WCF services?

Tags: wcf, deployment, tfs, release-management

I have one large solution containing 27 WCF services and 3 shared projects (DAL, Models, and Core).

Lets say something critical in the DAL changes. Now I need to publish all 27 WCF services. I am currently doing this manually by right clicking on each of the 27 and choosing publish. I have set up publish profiles on each of the services using "File System" as the publish method. As you can imagine this is quite a pain.

I have created different solution configurations and web.config transforms as well. This allows me to publish to production and the test box with different config contents. Going back to the original issue, when something low level changes in the DAL and I need to re-publish 27 times, I actually re-publish 54 times, 27 to the test box and then 27 to the live box.

How can you publish multiple WCF services or what are best practices for doing something like this? I'm using VS2013 and TFS2013.

FYI - we are currently installing and reading about the new release management tools for VS/TFS 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to write PowerShell sripts. Creating script might cause you pain, but the result will be great! Here is a guide how to do that: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Release Management tools for VS/TFS is the way forward.  You can create one component for each web service in Release Management tool and use IIS related activities inside the each
component.